# Why does the heap in the Overview pane not match the heap in the Counter pane?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome devtools to develop an interactive web application. During a Performance Recording, I recorded the the following JavaScript Heap behavior:

[image: JavaScript Heap]

The Counter Pane shows the heap gradually increasing for 15 seconds and then being reduced by garbage collect (9.4 MB - 10.4 MB). However, the "NET HEAP" plot at the top shows the heap mostly constant at 10.4 MB with discrete jumps down to 0.6 MB. The [Chrome tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/memory-problems#visualize_memory_leaks_with_timeline_recordings) seems to suggest that these two should be the same.

Why are they different? If this is expected behavior, what is the meaning of NET HEAP and why does it have discrete jumps down?